# I encountered EOF error in hacker rank engine while my code in my local machine works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am encountering this error in Hacker rank engine while running python3 on it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 8, in <module>
    name=input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

My code is this

```
phonebook = {}
total_entries = int(input("Total number of entries: "))
if 1 <= total_entries <= 10 ** 5:
    print("Enter names and number separated by space:")
    for entries in range(0, total_entries):
        items = input("Enter here:")
        items = items.split(" ")
        phonebook[items[0]] = int(items[1])
queries = []
while True:
    queries.append(input("Enter name to be searched:"))
    k = queries[-1]
    if not k:
        break
if 1 <= len(queries) <= 10 ** 5:
    for query in queries:
        if query == '':
            exit(0)
        elif query in phonebook.keys():
            print(f"{query}={phonebook.get(query)}")
        else:
            print("Not found")
```

The link to the question is this if you require in case: [Question Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/problem)

The code runs fine in my local machine. I don't know why it puts an error like this. Please suggest what I can do!

Answer (score 1):

The way you are reading the input is wrong.

Your code assumes that each name and number pair is inputted on a separate line, which is not the case.

Instead of calling `input()` when getting the name and number, you need to `input` once then use `split`, for example

```
name, number = input().split()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the HackerRank question, after n lines of input, there will be some "random" lines of input. So you do not know when the input ends. Hence you are getting the "EOF Error". One way to do it would be to use stdin as shown below:

```
from sys import stdin

phone={}
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    name=input()
    phone[name]=input()
for i in stdin:
    name=input()
    re=phone.get(name,"none")
    if re!="none":        
        print("%s=%s"%(name,re))
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

Your logic is wrong though. Since input is taken in a single line whereas you are taking two lines of input instead of one line

Comment: Did you check to copy-paste the code from my comment? Make sure you import the stdin from sys. I checked it and hence posted the code.

Comment: yes it didn't work I did a work arround and solved  the problem

Comment: but thanks for helping I used the get function to solve it